# Can I repeat the quests Quartermastery and Cleansing the Commonwealth forever?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been going back and forth between the Cambridge Police Station and various locations in the Commonwealth for some time now.

It seems to me like the quests **Quartermastery** (*"Recover the Flux sensor in ..."* - given by Scribe Haylen) and **Cleansing the Commonwealth** (*"Clear out ..."* - given by Knight Rhys) can be initiated again and again!

Do these quests ever end or can they be repeated forever?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are listed as repeatable quests on the Fallout wiki (see links below). So yes, you should be able to do them over and over. I've done each about 4+ times and while that is far from "forever", it supports the claim, despite the fact that the wiki for these articles does not yet contain full walkthroughs or the other usual detail compared to other quests (as of this writing).

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Quartermastery
http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cleansing_the_Commonwealth

Comment: Oh, sweet! Didn't even know that there was a wikia. Thank you.

Comment: Fallout wiki pages can change your entire Fallout experience @cubrr :)

Comment: @cubrr The other day, Scribe Haylen sent me to the same location four times in a row. It never had any enemies at it, not even the first time. Thanks for the XP Haylen!